# NuGet Package restore failed for project Miscellaneous Files: Value cannot be null or an empty string.in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I keep getting this error in VS2013. I checked this [SO post on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859591/nuget-package-restore-failed-for-project-miscellaneous-files-value-cannot-be-nu) and other search links and they say to upgrade to NuGet 2.8 which fixed this error of 2.7. I have and I keep getting this error. FWIW, its on a Unit Test project. It has something to do with the XUnit package because I get this error when I am using that package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NuGet Package restore failed for project Miscellaneous Files: Value cannot be null or an empty string. Parameter name: root. 0 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859591/nuget-package-restore-failed-for-project-miscellaneous-files-value-cannot-be-nu)

Answer (score 1):

Just download NuGet 2.8+

http://docs.nuget.org/consume/installing-nuget

They solved this problem, It's from their side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the .suo file, as suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20859591/nuget-package-restore-failed-for-project-miscellaneous-files-value-cannot-be-nu), worked for me when I was having this problem. 
I did shut down VS before deleting the file and restarted VS after the file was removed.